# What does this mean in C#?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

```
Console.WriteLine(" Give me a number");

double a;
double b;
double c;
double d;
double e;
double z;

double g;
double h;
double i;
double j;
double k;

Console.WriteLine("Give me a number");
a = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Give me a second number");
b = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Give me a third number");
c = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Give me a fourth number");
d = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Give me one more number");
e = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

g = (a - z) * (a - z);
h = (b - z) * (b - z);
i = (c - z) * (c - z);
j = (d - z) * (d - z);
k = (e - z) * (e - z);

z = ((a + b + c + d + e) / 2);

Console.ReadKey();
```

I am a beginner in C#. I don't know why but I am getting an error message when declaring `g= (a-z)*(a-z)`.

This is the error message that I get

> Use of unassigned local variable 'z'

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: I think you can accept my answer as it is solving your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Just provide initial values to  `z` 
like
`z = 0`

The error comes because you have not provided initial values to your variable z

Maybe you forgot to write

```
    z = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) ;
```

or you wanted to provide the value to z at compile time like

```
  z = 0 ;  //some arbitary value.
```

Also, since your datatype of `a` and `z` is `double`  you might want to do

```
  a = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) ;
```

rather than parsing a as a `float`
[Double.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The thing is that if i set z equal to zero I get a different answer than if I set it to five. And I need to set it to five because of the variance formula.

Comment: Then set it to 5! ofcourse, 0 is just an arbitary number, I used it  to illustrate my point that you need to initialize a local variable variable  before using it

Comment: Thats the thing. Do I have to set it to a numerical value? I want it so that the user is able to decide what number to enter.

Comment: You can use the following `z = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`. If you want to take the value of z from the user.

Answer (score 0):

This error because there is no default value for z.Just initialize

```
double z=0;
```

Comment: The thing is that if i set z equal to zero I get a different answer than if I set it to five. And I need to set it to five because of the variance formula.